# May I pass struct slice pointer as []interface pointer

Tags: go

May I pass an struct slice pointer as interface slice pointer ?

https://play.golang.org/p/EyhGYknZvT2

```
func (r *Randomizer) ShuffleAry(ary *[]interface{}) (v []interface{}) {
    r.mu.Lock()
    tmp := make([]int, len(*ary))
    v = make([]interface{}, len(*ary))
    for index := range tmp {
        tmp[index] = index
    }
    // v = append(v, *ary...)

    r.rand.Shuffle(len(tmp), func(i, j int) { tmp[i], tmp[j] = tmp[j], tmp[i] })
    for index, newIndex := range tmp {
        v[index] = (*ary)[newIndex]
    }
    r.mu.Unlock()
    return
}
```

Got `cannot use &txx (type *[]Tx) as type *[]interface {} in argument to r.ShuffleAry` error message

Comment: See [Can I convert a [\]T to an [\]interface{}?](https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface).  Not that it helps with your problem, but you can simplify the code by using argument `ary []interface{}`.  See https://play.golang.org/p/33Dmsbz1hOv

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface . Also Passing a pointer to a slice is wrong in almost all cases.

Comment: Note: Those aren't arrays. They're slices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no automatic conversion of arbitrary slice types to `[]interface{}`. See the [FAQ](https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface) for more information.

You may use the [reflect](https://godoc.org/reflect) package to solve the problem:

```
// Shuffle shuffles the slice src to the slice pointed to by dstp.
func (r *Randomizer) Shuffle(dstp interface{}, src interface{}) {

    // Create reflect values for each of the slices.
    dv := reflect.ValueOf(dstp).Elem()
    sv := reflect.ValueOf(src)

    // Make the destination slice and copy to it.
    dv.Set(reflect.MakeSlice(dv.Type(), sv.Len(), sv.Len()))
    reflect.Copy(dv, sv)

    // Shuffle the destination.
    r.mu.Lock()
    r.rand.Shuffle(dv.Len(), reflect.Swapper(dv.Interface()))
    r.mu.Unlock()
}
```

Use it like this:

```
r := NewRandomizer()
var rtx []Tx
r.Shuffle(&rtx, txx)
```

[Run it on the Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/UTVVYWZdW-H).

The code is a little simpler if you randomize in place:

```
// Shuffle shuffles the slice pointed to by sp.
func (r *Randomizer) Shuffle(s interface{}) {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(s)
    r.mu.Lock()
    r.rand.Shuffle(v.Len(), reflect.Swapper(v.Interface()))
    r.mu.Unlock()
}
```

[Run it on the Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/59ljVVTRfqd).\

I should also point out that it's not all that bad to write the code directly:

```
r := NewRandomizer()
rtx := append([]Tx(nil), txx...) // copy txx to rtx.
r.mu.Lock()
r.rand.Shuffle(len(rtx), reflect.Swapper(rtx))
r.mu.Unlock()
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/N6mv2z_KOCc).